# Anonymous function to wrap local variable and return new function

Tags: javascript, canvas, anonymous-function, kineticjs

I'm terribly sorry for asking yet another anonymous-function question, but it seams like every time I figure them out, javascript throws me another curve ball.

I am using [KineticJS](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-events-tutorials-introduction-with-kineticjs/) to create a number of circles then animate them like so (following [these tutorials](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-animate-position-tutorial/) )

```
for ( i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
{
   for ( j = 0; j < cols; j++ )
   {
      index = i * cols + j;
      circles [ index ] = new Kinetic.Circle({...});
      ...
   }
}
...
for ( i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
{
   for ( j = 0; j < cols; j++ )
   {
      index = i * cols + j;
      anims [ index ] = new Kinetic.Animation({func: function ( frame )
            {
               ( function ( innerCircle )
               {
                  ...
               } ( circles [ index ] ) );
            },
            node: layer
         }
      );
   }
}
```

My intention is to pass the current value of `index` when creating the anonymous function. Problem is that only the last image is being animated and I can't figure out why. Here is the [full jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pukster/bBskB/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function that is supposed to create a new variable scope is in the wrong place. It shoudl be outside the function being passed, and should *return* a new function.

The returned function will have access to the desired value.

```
for ( i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
{
   for ( j = 0; j < cols; j++ )
   {
      index = i * cols + j;
      anims [ index ] = new Kinetic.Animation({func: function(innerCircle) {
                                                        return function ( frame ) {

                                                        };
                                                      })(circles[index]),
            node: layer
         }
      );
   }
}
```

---

But honestly, don't inline functions like this. It becomes so much clearer when you make a named function that returns your function.

```
function makeFunc(innerCircle) {
    return function (frame) {
           // you can use innerCircle in here
    };
}

for ( i = 0; i < rows; i++ ) {
   for ( j = 0; j < cols; j++ ) {
      index = i * cols + j;
      anims [ index ] = new Kinetic.Animation({
         func: makeFunc(circles[index]),
         node: layer
      });
   }
}
```

Some people just love those inlined functions for some reason, but I think they just add clutter. A named function breaks up the code a bit, and adds a little documentation to the code.

Also, it's slightly more efficient because you're not making a new inlined function in every iteration of the loop. Instead you're reusing the same one to build the handler.

Comment: +1.  It's generally better practice to break out functions when using them inside of for loops (due to closures and readability)